# Search strings of an array in content of several div referenced by class and perform action depending on the condition

Tags: javascript

I have this basic code for the development of what I need, who can help me is a lot of help for me !!

note: I used the function .search () and replace () without getting good results, I do not know what else way to take

```js
var fjstr = document.getElementsByClassName("js-product-variants-list");

var fjinnerColor = '';

var fjscolor2 = ["Rojo-Wengue",
                     "Aqua-Natural",
                     "Gris/Decape",
                     "Rosa-Blanco",
                     "Turqueza-Wengue",
                     "Turqueza-Blanco",
                     "Naranja-Natural",
                     "Amarillo-Natural"];


var resultado = "";
var pos = -1

fjscolor2.forEach(function(element) {

    pos = fjstr.innerHTML.search(element.toString());

    if(pos!=-1){
    resultado += "<a href='#" + (fjscolor[i]) + "' ><li class='fj-product-color-icon' id='color-" + (fjscolor[i]) + "'></li></a>"
       document.getElementsByClassName('cont-product-variacion-color')[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML = resultado;
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you please ask in english?

Comment: Please, translate your question to english, then we can help you

Comment: Only English is supported here.